# Can't Archive xcode project

Tags: xcode, release, archive

I'm trying to archive a project to be able to download it on my iPhone, although I get the following error:

> "swift stdlib tool Error. Task failed with exit 1 signal 0"
>
> Users/[myusername]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/InstaPetrol-ecrfzlyxswrpqhdhhkbpqgbbkwlv/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/InstaPetrol/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/InstaPetrol.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib: replacing existing signature
>   /Users/[myusername]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/InstaPetrol-ecrfzlyxswrpqhdhhkbpqgbbkwlv/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/InstaPetrol/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/InstaPetrol.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib: unknown error -1=ffffffffffffffff
>   error: Task failed with exit 1 signal 0 {
>       /usr/bin/codesign '--force' '--sign' '06EEC2F5E4124B35FA197B18BAEE0F92088C76C7' '--verbose' '/Users/[myusername]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/InstaPetrol-ecrfzlyxswrpqhdhhkbpqgbbkwlv/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/InstaPetrol/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/InstaPetrol.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib'
>   }

I tried doing everything from checking and signing certificates to deleting the deriveddata folder.

Comment: I faced the same issue last weekend. Spent much time taking care of. **Same error.** Sorry @rmaddy, that question didn't help - so I'm trying to reopen this. My "normal" upgrade to Xcode 9.2 killed things. Behavior question: Does everything build properly and run in the simulator but not on any device? If so, I'll post a link (and explanation) that finally helped. **Not a dup.**

Comment: @dfd You should post an answer on the other question. There's no need to spread answers across different copies of the same issue.

Comment: @dfd yes that's exactly the problem!

Comment: @rmaddy, it's hard to do that. I understand where you're coming from, but it was a question from months (maybe years ago) that I "inferred" could help me - and all I did was up vote the answer.

Comment: Here's what I did: (1) After upgrading from 9.1 to Xcode 9.2, a project I had would not build, giving me the same error. (2) I both cleaned my project and cleaned my project folder - Option-Project menu. (3) After finding out my iOS developer cert had expired on 8 December (even though the expiration date was 15 December), I recreated the cert and cleaned that up. (4) I found a question/answer suggesting going *back* from iOS 11 to iOS 10, making things universal - my project was already iOS 9 and universal. (5) I shut down Xcode and started back up....

Comment: (6) Only *then* did I find people having issues with builds *working* in the simulator but not on *devices*. I powered my two devices down *after* deleting the app. No go. (7) I found suggestions on moving the cert in your keychain from "Local" to "System". Didn't help. (8) Finally, I found either a comment or an answer - all I can remember is the user name was "Damn...." and the comment began with "Damn Xcode..." saying that *the issue* required a reboot of your Mac. Upon that, opening Xcode brought up a prompt to access the keychain. I gave it my Mac admin password, and all worked.

Comment: You're a life saver! Thank you very much!